# Why is my code not breaking out of my while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have this code to display powers of two:

```
print ("How many powers of two would you like to see?")
number=int(input())
values=[2]
count=1
while count <=  number:
    length=len(values)
    index=length-1
    number=values[index]*2
    values.append(number)
    count=count+1 
print (values)
```

My code is updating the value of count, but it won't break out of the while loop.

Comment: Probably because you are changing "number" inside the loop - and not only "count"

Answer (score 2):

You compare `count <= number` in every while loop, but you increase `number` faster than `count` inside the loop. Don't touch `number` in the loop, like this:

```
print("How many powers of two would you like to see?")
number = int(input())

values = [2]
count = 1
while count <= number:
    length = len(values)
    index = length - 1
    number_tmp = values[index]*2
    values.append(number_tmp)
    count += 1    
print(values)
```

But a more pythonic way would be something like:

```
print("How many powers of two would you like to see?")
number = int(input())

values = [2**(n+1) for n in range(number)]

print(values)
```

Comment: If it was helpful, please consider accepting the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the value for number, after the 40th iteration, `count = 40` but

```
number = 2199023255552
```

And after the 1000th iteration, `count = 1000` but

```
number = 21430172143725346418968500981200036211228096234110672148875007767407021022498722449863967576313917162551893458351062936503742905713846280871969155149397149607869135549648461970842149210124742283755908364306092949967163882534797535118331087892154125829142392955373084335320859663305248773674411336138752
```

So count will never exceed `number` and the loop will never break. You can change this by not changing the value of `number` inside the loop.